# Why FileSystem.get() returns com.pepperdata.supervisor.agent.resource.DistributedFileSystemWrapperClassic

Tags: java, hadoop, oozie

The following piece of code is part of our production system.

```
import com.turn.util.hadoop.ConfigurationFactory;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;

FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(ConfigurationFactory.newInstance().getConfiguration());
if (fs instanceof DistributedFileSystem) { ACTION }
```

When oozie launched the job. The ACTION part of code was not executed. And `fs.getClass().getCanonicalName()` returns `com.pepperdata.supervisor.agent.resource.DistributedFileSystemWrapperClassic`.

I tried to run the above code mannualy through bin/java, providing the same classpath and java properties that I get from oozie syslog. The result is `org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem`.

I am using hadoop-common-2.0.0-cdh4.7.1.jar and the classpath has
CDH-4.7.1-1.cdh4.7.1.p0.47/lib/hadoop-0.20-mapreduce/lib/PepperdataSupervisor.jar. and   /opt/pepperdata/lib/PepperdataSupervisor.jar

I am new to java ecosystem. What is what is the com.pepperdata.supervisor.agent.resource.DistributedFileSystemWrapperClassic? Why the result being different between manual run and oozie launch?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Pepperdata Supervisor runs on the Resource Manager (or JobTracker) node and communicates with agents that run on every data node in the cluster."

com.pepperdata.supervisor.agent.resource.DistributedFileSystemWrapperClassic
extends
org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem
extends
org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem

So when using pepperdata, we should not test the returned fs as a subclass or do a manual type cast to of org.apache.hadoop.fs.DistributedFileSystem. Instead, we should use the returned fs directly as a org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem. eg.

```
FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(ConfigurationFactory.newInstance().getConfiguration());
fs.exists(inputPath);
```